# php preg_replace ignore class attribute if not exist

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

hello I have the following code :

```
$content1 = '<img src="image1.png" class="image1"><img src="image2.png"><img src="image3.png" class="image3">';
```

when I use this code :

```
preg_replace('~<img\s*.*?\s*class\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"\s*.*?>~i','<img src="image-replaced" class="$1">', $content1);
```

this is what I get :

```
<img src="image-replaced" class="image1"><img src="image-replaced" class="image3">
```

as you can see this `<img src="image2.png">` got ignored because it doesn't have a class attribute so it didn't get replaced.
now what I want to do is if img tag has class attribute in it then it get replaced if not then replace it and keep class blank like this:

```
<img src="image2.png" class="">
```

I appreciate any help from you.

Comment: can anyone help me please?

Comment: why don't you just repace the src attribute and leave the image tag alone, unless i missed something, let me know if you want to do that I can do easy regx for that

Comment: For highly structured data you should use functions/libraries/etc. that were made for working with it. Regular expressions get unwieldy when used for stuff like this.

Comment: this regex code really worked for me : ~<img\s*.*?(?:class="(.*?)")?>~i

Comment: @chris85: `chris85` deleted their answer for some reason, but I'm sure they were glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using regular expression, you may consider using [**DOM**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for this.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML($content1); // load the HTML data

$imgs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach ($imgs as $img) {
  if ($img->hasAttribute('class')) {
      $img->setAttribute('src', 'image-replaced');
  } else {
      ## Otherwise set an empty class if you desire. 
      $img->setAttribute('class', '');
  }
}
```

If you must use regular expression, I would consider using a callback:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('~<img src="([^"]*)"(?: class="([^"]*)")?>~i', 
  function($m) {
    return '<img src="'.(isset($m[2])?'image-replaced':$m[1]).'" class="'.($m[2]?:'').'">';
  }, $str);
```

[**eval.in**](https://eval.in/405545)

Comment: I didn't misread the question. This does exactly what the question asks ... `if img tag has class attribute in it then it gets replaced` the above checks to see if the **img** has a class attribute, if so it replaces the **src** with `image-replaced`, `if not then replace it and keep class blank` if it does not have a class attribute, it creates an empty class attribute.

Comment: this regex code really worked for me : ~<img\s*.*?(?:class="(.*?)")?>~i

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just replace the contents of the `src` attribute and leave the class and other stuff untouched

```
 preg_replace('/src=\"[^\"]+\"/', 'src="image-replaced.png"', '<img src="image1.png" class="image1"><img src="image2.png"><img src="image3.png" class="image3">');
```

https://regex101.com/r/hR9iH0/1

> if img tag has class attribute in it then it get replaced if not then replace it and keep class blank like this:

Let me help you all out,

If the image tag has a class replace the src.
If the image does not have a class replace the src and leave the class blank,

having `class=""` and no class be the same thing.

Comment: The result would end up being `<img src="image-replaced.png" class="image1"><img src="image-replaced.png"><img src="image-replaced.png" class="image3">`

Comment: And?  Isn't that what they should be?

Comment: I don't think so... they want `class=""` in image2, and I'm not sure the extension should be added either.

Comment: Re: "having class="" and no class be the same thing.", would essentially make this entire question pointless then I'd imagine.

Comment: No, because the original regx fails to match on images without class attribute.  In which case it blenders the output.   That is the problem.  `How do i replace the image in both cases.`

Comment: Yes, good point, although what if `image1.png` is `image1.jpg`, you replace it with a `.png`

Comment: That wasn't part of the question, but you whould need to capture the image extension with `/src=\"[^\.]+(\.[a-z]+)\"/i` and then replace with `image-replaced\1`  Assuming there is no double extensions, but where would it end if you went down that rabbit hole.

Comment: this regex code really worked for me : ~<img\s*.*?(?:class="(.*?)")?>~i

Comment: @mus: Indeed, and I'm surprised the person who posted it deleted their answer.

Comment: An optional non capture group, works to, unless you have `alt="some-image"` then it breaks again.  But for the question as posted it would be sufficient

Comment: haha yes I don't know why he deleted his answer... I just wanted to give him an upvote and mark his answer as accepted

Comment: his loss I suppose, however I try to do simpler = better, often by simplifying the answer the solution is more robust.